# Select from multiple tables group by ID with time

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I'm trying to select data from multiple tables but I'm not sure an inner join is the right approach. I have two tables, one that has `comments.userid` and `comments.comment`, another that has `votes.userid`, and both have a `time` column as well.

```
select comments.comment, voted.time, comments.time
from voted
inner join comments on voted.userid = comments.userid
where voted.userid = '12345'
order by voted.time
```

But now my rows have values in `voted.time` and `comments.time` even though they should be separate. Is there a way to just return either a comment or a vote but joined by the userid and sorted by overall time?

Comment: "But my rows have values in voted.time and comments.time even though they should be separate" ?? The query should return three separate columns. What exactly are you asking? Do you want the voted time OR the comments.time? The greater of them? The less of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. If you put this into a view, you can issue ORDER BY when you call the view. Filtering by userid can also be performed in view call.

```
select 'V' as type, v.userid, v.time from votes v where v.userid = '1234'
union
select 'C' as type, c.userid, c.time from comments c where c.userid = '1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, you're filter and join logic looks correct.  Simply add/remove columns in the select statement that you want/don't want returned in the retrieved data set.

Comment: The problem is let's say I have two comments and 200 votes. Those two comments get repeated a bunch of times in the result set.

Comment: Without knowing much about your system, it sounds like comments -> votes is a one-many relationship.  The 'many' side will repeat for each 'one' side.  Try doing a 'SELECT *' from the tables and see which data is repeating.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For user X there are 2 comments and 2 accompanying times, and for the same user X there are 200 votes and 200 separate times. How can I get both of them in one query?

Comment: As @Mevdiven said you could put them in a view.  Depending, you could also join the two seperate data sets via the UNION operator.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html